# Where did the money come from to build the Colosseum?

Tags: ancient-rome, economy, roman-empire, rome

Where did the money come from to finance the building of the Colosseum?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was financed by the emperors, and hence it's ultimate financing was from taxes and spoils of war. An [article in Biblical Archeology](http://members.bib-arch.org/publication.asp?PubID=BSBA&Volume=27&Issue=4&ArticleID=1) review shows findings that suggest that the Colosseum primarily was financed by spoils or war, and in fact suggests it may be the sacking of Jerusalem that financed much of it, but that is conjecture.